# Select name where case value > another case value + 2

Tags: mysql

Having some trouble with the last part of this query.

What I am looking for is WHERE capvalue < desiredCapValue + 2.

Meaning if capValue = 1, I'm looking for any desiredCapValue of 3 or greater.

```
SELECT instanceName, capacitySizeName, desiredCapacitySizeName, desiredCapValue, capvalue FROM
(SELECT instance_name AS instanceName, capacity_size_name AS capacitySizeName, 
(CASE capacity_size_name WHEN 'small' THEN '1' WHEN 'medium' THEN '2' WHEN 'large' THEN '3' WHEN 'xlarge' THEN '4' WHEN 'xxlarge' THEN '5' WHEN 'mega' THEN '6' WHEN 'ultra' THEN '7' WHEN 'giga' THEN '8' WHEN 'tera' THEN '9' WHEN 'peta' THEN '10' END) AS `capValue`, 
u_desired_capacity_size_name AS desiredCapacitySizeName, 
CASE u_desired_capacity_size_name WHEN 'small' THEN '1' WHEN 'medium' THEN '2' WHEN 'large' THEN '3' WHEN 'xlarge' THEN '4' WHEN 'xxlarge' THEN '5' WHEN 'mega' THEN '6' WHEN 'ultra' THEN '7' WHEN 'giga' THEN '8' WHEN 'tera' THEN '9' WHEN 'peta' THEN '10' END AS `desiredCapValue` 
FROM mysql_view 
WHERE used_for = 'Production')A 
WHERE capvalue < desiredCapValue+2 LIMIT 10
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which kind of trouble you have  ...  you have error ?? show the exact error message,.. wrong result  ?? show a proper data sample, your actual result and your expected result

Comment: YOu defined the capvalue  and desiredCapValue as String in the subquery. If you need to compare by number, you can change the CASE to return number'

Comment: The error is:  Arithmetic operation requires numeric operands: desiredcapvalue + 2

Comment: @PeterHe - spot on! I missed that I had put '1' instead of just 1. TY!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need  number (not string) for a valid aritmetic eval and right capvalue < desiredCapValue+2  comparison

```
  SELECT instanceName
    , capacitySizeName
    , desiredCapacitySizeName
    , desiredCapValue
    , capvalue 
  FROM ( 
      SELECT instance_name AS instanceName
      , capacity_size_name AS capacitySizeName
      ,  (CASE capacity_size_name 
            WHEN 'small' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'medium' THEN 2 
            WHEN 'large' THEN 3 
            WHEN 'xlarge' THEN 4
            WHEN 'xxlarge' THEN 5 
            WHEN 'mega' THEN 6 
            WHEN 'ultra' THEN 7 
            WHEN 'giga' THEN 8 
            WHEN 'tera' THEN 9 
            WHEN 'peta' THEN 10 END) AS `capValue`
      , u_desired_capacity_size_name AS desiredCapacitySizeName
      , CASE u_desired_capacity_size_name 
            WHEN 'small' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'medium' THEN 2 
            WHEN 'large' THEN 3 
            WHEN 'xlarge' THEN 4 
            WHEN 'xxlarge' THEN 5 
            WHEN 'mega' THEN 6 
            WHEN 'ultra' THEN 7
            WHEN 'giga' THEN 8 
            WHEN 'tera' THEN 9 
            WHEN 'peta' THEN 10 END AS `desiredCapValue` 
  FROM mysql_view 
  WHERE used_for = 'Production'
  ) A 
  WHERE capvalue < desiredCapValue+2 
  LIMIT 10
```